# Exclude nodes between elements with an extra twist

Tags: xpath

Have a tricky XPath issue that I can't quite seem to get. Let's say I have the following:

```
<content>
  <body>
      <block id="123">
        <html>
          <p align="left">Some text</p>
        </html>
      </block>
      <block id="abc8383">
        <html>
          <p></p>
        </html>
      </block>
      <block id="456">
        <html>
          <p><span>Some more text</span></p>
         </html>
      </block>
      <block id="789">
        <html>
          <p></p>
        </html>
      </block>  
      <block id="012356">
        <html>
          <p class="finalBlock"><h3>content</h3><span>xyz</span></p>
        </html>
      </block>  
  </body>
</content>
```

I want to select all  nodes **above** the  element which has a **p** tag inside the xhtml with a "finalBlock" class, except for the ones that do not have context (node text - e.g. block id 789). However, this rule should only apply until the first node with content is encountered again - afterwards the empty  elements should all be included. This means that the input above should produce the following output:

```
<content>
  <body>
      <block id="123">
        <html>
          <p align="left">Some text</p>
        </html>
      </block>
      <block id="abc8383">
        <html>
          <p></p>
        </html>
      </block>
      <block id="456">
        <html>
          <p><span>Some more text</span></p>
         </html>
      </block>  
      <block id="012356">
        <html>
          <p class="finalBlock"><h3>content</h3><span>xyz</span></p>
        </html>
      </block>  
  </body>
</content>
```

Where the  element with an id of 789 was removed, but all others were kept. I've managed to craft the XPath query that excludes the block elements I want (empty ones), but am struggling with implementing the "between" rule. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the expression excluding the empty block elements

```
//block[html/p]/html/p[normalize-space(.) != '']
```

Comment: Can you please show the XPath expression you mention in the last paragraph?

Comment: Sure - it's: //block[html/p]/html/p[normalize-space(.) != '']

Comment: Your XPath selects a `p`. You want to select a `p` or a `block`?

Comment: Your desired output even has the `content` node. XPath will only allow you to select certain portions of the document and not to transform it like this. To perform such a transformation, you'll need XSLT. BTW, here's an expression that selects the blocks that meet your criteria `//block[html/p[normalize-space(.) != ''] or following-sibling::block/html/p[not(@class = 'finalBlock') and normalize-space(.) != ''] ]`, at least for the input and output you've shown. I assumed there can only be one `finalBlock` and that a `finalBlock` does not count as a `first node with content encountered again`

Comment: Thanks Tom - what you've provided seems to work as advertised. I do indeed use XSLT, but it's big and does a million other things, so I wanted to ask the question in the context of XPath which I'll be plugging into the XSLT shortly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression selects "the element which has a `p` tag inside the `html`, with a `finalBlock` class", which is `<block id="012356">`:

```
//*[html/p[@class='finalBlock']]
```

This one selects all the `block` nodes that precede it ("all nodes above" - which does *not* include the ancestor nodes):

```
//*[html/p[@class='finalBlock']]/preceding-sibling::*
```

You can add a predicate to restrict that to only the ones that have a non-empty `p` descendant:

```
//*[html/p[@class='finalBlock']]/preceding-sibling::*[descendant::p[string()]]
```

And the ones that have an empty `p` descendant, except the most recent one:

```
//*[html/p[@class='finalBlock']]/preceding-sibling::*[descendant::p[not(string())]][not(position() = 1)]
```

If you perform a *union* of the previous two expressions, you will obtain all the `block` nodes that satisfy the requirements you stated:

```
//*[html/p[@class='finalBlock']]/preceding-sibling::*[descendant::p[string()]] 
| //*[html/p[@class='finalBlock']]/preceding-sibling::*[descendant::p[not(string())]][not(position() = 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks - this works great with one small exception... I need it to also return the block element with the "finalBlock" class as well - what would be the modification needed to the above for that?

Comment: You can add it to your result nodeset (it's selected in the first expression above: `//*[html/p[@class='finalBlock']]` or `//block[html/p[@class='finalBlock']]`. Simply append `| //block[html/p[@class='finalBlock']]`.